# How to prevent Google Chrome from downloading a JSON file when executing searches?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-search

Sometimes when I make a search in Google using Google Chrome for Windows (version 17 right now, but it occurred with previous versions), it downloads a file name "search" and it contains JSON data.

I think this file was meant to be included in the HTML code, but somehow it is downloaded.

How to fix this behavior?

Comment: Still occurs on Chrome 18

Comment: Fastestchrome extension try to disable it and check the solution.

Comment: What extensions do you have installed/enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a lot of people, disabling the FastestChrome Extension solved the search.json problem.

[source](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/4rAd5jl6pqE)

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a Google Instant bug -- clearing the cookies solved the problem for me. In Chrome, be sure to clear the cookies from "The beginning of time" rather than just the past hour.

Answer (score 0):

worked for me: FastestChrome Options / Popup Bubble / Search Engines: uncheck google AND Google Maps.

so you don't have to disable FastestChrome completely.

source same as harrymc's